# What does the |= operator mean in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I want to know the value of `result` in the following two cases:

1.

```
var result = false;
result |= false;
```

2.

```
var result = false;
result |= true;
```

Comment: Look up what `console.log(result);` does, then perform the experiment.  See green's answer for why.

Comment: You probably wouldn't have the downvotes if you hadn't phrases the body of your question in a way that can be totally answered by just running your samples in the console. Your actually interesting question is only asked in the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's the BitWise OR Assignment. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/81bads72%28v=vs.94%29.aspx

so `result |= expression` is the same as `result = result | expression`

Answer (score 1):

The `|` operator is the Bitwise OR operator. Rather than doing a standard binary OR (truth table below) the `|` operator will perform a binary OR for each bit of both operands.

Binary OR

```
x|y|q
0|0|0
1|0|1
0|1|1
1|1|1
```

Example

```
3 | 5
// in binary
0011 | 0101
// as a truth table

x|y|q
0|0|0
0|1|1
1|0|1
1|1|1

0011 | 0101 = 0111
// in decimal
3 | 5 = 7
```

Using the Bitwise OR operator in conjunction with an equals sign turns it into an assignment statement, in a similar way to `+=` or `-=` or any of the other logic/arithmetic operators. It is just a shorthand for `result = result | operand`.

It's important to note that if you use the operator with boolean values (true or false), they are coerced into numeric values (1 and 0, respectively) before being compared in the above way.

Answer (score 0):

It is an Assignment Operator of a BitWise Operator "|" which returns a one in each bit position for which the corresponding bits of either or both operands are ones.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Arithmetic_operators